# Dash dropdown navigation

Tags: plotly-dash

I'm trying to create an interactive menu in a `Dash` dashboard using a simple `Dropdown` element. The idea would simply to change the url pathname whenever the value in the Dropdown element changes. I've looked around how to manage that with a `callback` and couldn't find how to properly do that. Could you please help me on that? Cheers.

```
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc

def Header(app):
    return html.Div([get_header(app)])

def get_header(app):
    logo = html.A(
        html.Img(
            src=app.get_asset_url("logo.jpeg"),
            className="logo",
        ),
        href="google.com",
    )

    dropdown = dcc.Dropdown(
        options=[
            {'label': 'Overview', 'value': 'Overview'},
            {'label': 'Details', 'value': 'Iteration 1'},
            {'label': 'Raw Data', 'value': 'Raw Data'},
        ],
        value='Overview',
    )
    
    ddcontainer = html.Div(
        [dropdown],
        id="dd-container"
    )

    header = html.Div([logo, ddcontainer])
    return header
```

Comment: I think you need the `dcc.Location` component, and output to that from a callback.

Comment: @coralvanda Could you please explain a bit more on how to implement that?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation [here](https://dash.plotly.com/urls)